# Why window.innerHeight > document.body.scrollHeight?

Tags: html, css, dom

On example.com size we have:

```
window.innerHeight # 314
document.body.scrollHeight # 308
```

Why window.innerHeight > document.body.scrollHeight? I think that scrollHeight always be the largest ones?

Comment: Well, body.scrollHeight is the actual height of the page itself (with all the content), the other is just the height of the window :)

Comment: Also, see [window.innerHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/innerHeight) and [element.scrollHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight) for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

`window` and `document.body` are different objects so they can have different heights.

Answer (score 0):

`window.innerHeight` Is just the height of the "what you see when the page loads". Whereas `document.body.scrollHeight` includes height of all the contents of the page.

Technical definitions:

MDN

> `window.innerHeight` is the height of the browser window's viewport.

W3 Schools

> The `scrollHeight` property returns the entire height of an element in pixels, including padding, but not the border, scrollbar or margin.

But here `scrollHeight` is used on `body`, so it returns the scroll Height of the body, That is, The whole page itself with all the contents.

Answer (score 0):

The Window innerHeight property is used for returning the height of a window’s content area. It is a read-only property and returns a number which represents the height of the browser window’s content area in pixels I.e viewport height.(source geek for geeks).

Syntax:-window.innerHeight

document.body.scrollHeight is the height of the body content which is definitely smaller than a window.innerHtml
Syntax:- document.body.scrollHeight